# Wide table in scroll auto div with flex, misses some col tag styles

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox, chromium

I faced a weird issue while trying to style last 2 column of one of my wide html tables using `colgroup` and `col` tags.

### Which browsers:

I tested on 2 chromium based browsers, google chrome and opera, issue was persistent.
But when tested on Mozilla Firefox, issue was not there at all.

### Issue:

After like an hour of debugging, i managed to workaround the issue but i was able to reproduce the issue in a raw html document. 
Which can be viewed in full at https://affectionate-lamport-fa8d14.netlify.app or minimal reproduction can be see below:

```css
table, td, tr, th, {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-size: 25px;
}
th, td {
  padding: 10px 22px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
body {
  font-size: 25px;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
.wrap {
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.bg-warning {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col span="20">
    <col span="2" class="bg-warning">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Category 1</th>
      <th colspan="2">C1</th>
      <th colspan="2">Some long name category</th>
      <th colspan="2">Category 10</th>
      <th colspan="2">klj kwjbhd ejk </th>
      <th colspan="2">Something else</th>
      <th colspan="2">Maybe something more</th>
      <th colspan="2">And so on</th>
      <th colspan="2">Something weird</th>
      <th colspan="2">Other stuff</th>
      <th colspan="2">Not done by Test Company 1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td >#</td>
      <td >Amount</td>
      <td >#</td>
      <td >Amount</td>
      <td >#</td>
      <td >Amount</td>
      <td >#</td>
      <td >Amount</td>
      <td >#</td>
      <td >Amount</td>
      <td >#</td>
      <td >Amount</td>
      <td >#</td>
      <td >Amount</td>
      <td >#</td>
      <td >Amount</td>
      <td >#</td>
      <td >Amount</td>
      <td >#</td>
      <td >Amount</td>
      <td >#</td>
      <td >Amount</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

As you can see, `bg-warning` class is not being applied on last table column(which is of 2 colspan), *issue arises only in chromium browsers, as mentioned above*.

### Whats going on, what was workaround:

When a wide **`table` with `width: 100%`** sits **inside a `flex-column` and `scroll auto` div**, its width is limited to screen size, even though full table is rendered and upon scroll we can see whole table.

This issue is not notice-able usually, but if I try to apply some css styles/class to last 2 columns with something like:

```
<colgroup>
  <col span="20">
  <col span="2" class="bg-warning">
</colgroup>
```

They don't get applied, **my styles are applied if i change `width` css property of `table` from `100%` to `fit-content`**. (Here is a gif for explanation from the demo page: https://gifyu.com/image/luCZ)

***There is more to the issue though, adding it here for just completeness sake, main issue is as described above***, there is a weird partial CSS style being applied on scroll which i could not re-produce in my reproduction HTML demo. Which also disappears, see the gif below for some understanding of that as well. Here it is gif: https://gifyu.com/image/luFZ

### Question:

**Is there a good known explanation of this behavior, it certainly looks like a bug, if it is a bug please confirm and guide me where to report this bugs, I would like to report this bug myself if it is actually a bug and not a known quirk of some sort.**

**Note:** Answer to only re-produced example should be enough.

Comment: *"...on my actual site (which i can't give access to)…"*. We shouldn't need access to your site. We shouldn't have to visit third-party links at all. All code necessary to reproduce the problem should be included in your question ([per the guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)).

Comment: @Michael_B Thankyou for guiding, I will update my question shortly. It does not let me add gifs which are greater than 2mb, which i will have to keep to links. I will try to explain in text and include whole page for re-production.

Comment: @Michael_B I have added minimal re-production steps, please withdraw your close vote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have been fixed in latest versions of chromium.

Cannot reproduce now. So closing this out. Don't exactly know which PR or issue fixed this. But it is fixed.